# How to take out percentage in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, percentage

I have a sql students attendance table where I have entered values like this:

```
Student_id total_classes class_attended
1          31            26 
2          31            21
3          31            17
4          31            21
5          31            29
```

I want to calculate the attendance percentage of `student_id` with 1.
Im looking for how to frame sql statement for the above..

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Do you know how to write a basic `select` statement? Do you know how to calculate a percentage?

Comment: Im a beginner learner of mysql...trying to frame small databases so struggling with queries ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to divide the number of attended classes with the total and then multiply by 100:

```
SELECT student_id, ROUND(class_attended/total_classes*100) total FROM student
```

The above will return the following result:

```
+------------+-------+
| student_id | total |
+------------+-------+
|          1 |    84 |
|          2 |    68 |
|          3 |    55 |
|          4 |    68 |
|          5 |    94 |
+------------+-------+
```

Comment: yeah it worked...:-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a select query, something like

SELECT class_attended/total_classes AS AttendencePercentage 
FROM attendance 
WHERE Student_id = '1'